# C# WPF Check-up a ListView Item By Index?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use C# WPF. I want to checkup list view items by their index. How do I accomplish that?

Code I tried-

```
int index= 10;
this.lstView1.Items[index].Checked=true;
```

It worked in WinForms, but not working anymore after migrating to XAML.

My XAML:

```
    <ListView Height="400" Width="400"
      Name="lstView1"                       
      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Name="chk" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="File" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding File}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Author" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Group"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: you want to select it?

Comment: What are you binding the lstview1 to? You should be updating the source, not the control.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I'll take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index= 10;

//selected
this.lstView1.SelectedItems.Add(this.lvUsers.Items[index]);

//checked
((User)this.lstView1.Items[index]).IsChecked = true;
```

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for your answer. I appreciate that. I want to mark the checkbox of 10th item as checked (not select entire row).

Comment: Can you send the xaml?

Comment: Sure, I have just added.

Comment: Try this ((User)this.lstView1.Items[index]).IsChecked = true;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, I get this error: 'User' does not contain a definition for 'IsChecked' and no accessible extension method 'IsChecked' accepting a first argument

Comment: Replace User by the class name that populates the values IsChecked,ID, File, Author.

Comment: Still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

you have Model class?
if you use data Binding, you need to Model calss

```
int index= 10;
(this.lstView1.ItemsSource[index] as YourModel).Checked=true;
```